# Grub error 'lvmid/xxx' not found

Tags: arch-linux, grub, luks, dm-crypt

I have a similar problem to this one: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249535. However, the fix does not work for me.

So I am trying to install arch linux in a dm-encrypted partition.

I have partitioned my drives like so:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1       259:0    0 1.8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0 476.4G  0 part  
  └─cryptlvm 254:0    0 476.4G  0 crypt /
      └─Volumes-swap 254:1  0  4G 0 lvm   [SWAP]
      └─Volumes-root 254:2  0  32G 0 lvm   /
      └─Volumes-swap 254:3  0  1.8T 0 lvm   /home
```

I have set the hooks in mkinitcpio and added the following line to /etc/default/grub

```
cryptdevice=UUID=98b562f4-a61a-462e-bae2-116c41b8ab83:cryptlvm root=/dev/Volumes/root
```

while chrooting into /mnt, blkid gives me this:

```
...
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="98b562f4-a61a-462e-bae2-116c41b8ab83" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="ec7ff919-01"
...
```

When I then try to restart and boot, this gives me the following error:

```
Enter passphrase for hd1,msdos2 (98b562f4a61a462ebae2116c41b8ab83):
error: access denied.
error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: disk `lvmid/CesI71-3km7-dJyq-60mN-m2zj-UWG5-XKbJtu/TIqMB9-9ueN-x2QQ-FV2j-RiBH-oKRp-qm1HvA' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have confirmed that the LUKS container is of type luks1. Before, I had a luks2 container; it would give a similar mistake, but even before letting me type the passphrase.

/boot/grub/grub.cfg read:

```
if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
    font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
insmod gcry_ri jndael
insmod gcry_ri jndael
insmod gcry_sha256
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
cryptomount -u 98b562f4a61a462ebae2116c41b8ab83
set root='lvmid/CesI73-3km7-dJyq-60mN-m2zj-UWG5-XKbJtu/TIqMB9-9ueN-x2QQ-FV2j-RiBH-oKRp-qm1HvA'
...
```

I have checked and doublechecked for typos, but to me everything seems fine so far.

I am stuck and would appreciated any hints on what I might have done wrong...